# Same shell script produces different results when called from GitHub actions vs Bitbucket workflow

Tags: github-actions, bitbucket-pipelines

I've noticed that GitHub action does not fail as expected. The same shell script is used in bitbucket pipeline and it fails there as expected.
The script is https://github.com/pavelfomin/gphoto-manager/blob/master/scripts/check-release.sh.
It returns 1 if the version in the pom.xml exists as a tag already.

I've tested the script locally and it does return 1 when tag already exists.

GitHub action: https://github.com/pavelfomin/gphoto-manager/actions/runs/570220185
https://github.com/pavelfomin/gphoto-manager/blob/master/.github/workflows/maven.yml

BitBucket pipeline: https://bitbucket.org/pvlf/gphoto-manager/addon/pipelines/home#!/results/2
https://github.com/pavelfomin/gphoto-manager/blob/master/bitbucket-pipelines.yml

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried ```[ $? == 1 ] && exit 1``` ? Instead of ||

Comment: The script returns 0 if tag does not exist (`git tag -l | grep $version` returns 1) so `[ $? == 1 ]` returns 0 in that case. If tag does exist (`git tag -l | grep $version` returns 0) then 1 is returned by the script hence `|| exit 1`. The script does work as expected when I run it locally and in bitbucket. It appears that github action ignores the status. Or somehow the result is different when the script is executed by github action.

Comment: The root cause was the lack of fetched tags in the repo so the `git tag` did not list any tags. I've posted the details in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by `actions/checkout@v2` fetching the git repository with `--depth=1` and [without fetching the tags](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/217) by default. The solution is to specify `fetch-depth: "0"`

```
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        # 0 indicates all history for all branches and tags
        fetch-depth: "0"
```